# Beginner - Java Programming While Loop

Tags: java, while-loop

This code keeps on looping every time I enter something. How to fix it?

```
public void inputPlayer()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(name.length() < 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Name: ");
        this.setName(input.nextLine());
        //name = input.nextLine();

        if(name.length() < 1)
            System.err.println("Must have one or more characters");
    }
}
```

Heres' a screenshot of the whole thing:

[image]

Comment: What actually you want ?

Comment: Unless `this.setName` changes name (don't know, you haven't given the code), nothing changes the guard condition, so it will never break.

Comment: while(name.length() < 1) where is name declared?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo have a look at the image he posted, theres everything.

Comment: Don't post code as images, post text.

Comment: @AndyTurner hey sorry about that, i just thought the code was too long :P

Comment: @Google0593 Definitely best to post a nice short code snippet of what you think is broken - just unfortunate it chopped the error out this time, but at least with the screenshot this time we did see inputs/outputs and the full listing :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is visible in the screenshot, and is with your `setName()` method, which is currently:

```
public void setName(String newName) {
    newName = name;
}
```

The assignment is the wrong way around, so you never update your `name` field. It should be `name = newName;`.

Comment: @JoshuadV I'd have expected some angry IDE squiggles or the like, but in a simple class like that it stood out well enough regardless.

Comment: Beat me to it by a  few seconds.

Comment: Hey edd thanks for your help! really appreciate it! :D

Answer (score 1):

because your setName function is wrong

it should be:

```
    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }
```

you put newName = name;

Comment: Hello hughzi! thanks for the help man! :D you guys are really fast at replying.